# How do you keep GPG from asking for PinEntry?

Tags: python, gnupg

I'm calling GPG from python like this.  You would think that `--batch` and `--no-tty` would stop it from popping open the PinEntry Dialog in KDE.  What am I missing?

```
subprocess.Popen(['gpg', '--list-packets', '--batch', '--no-tty'],...
```

Comment: I don't know if you are aware but there is a package called `python-gnupg` that may simplify you the python programming :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the version of GnuPG you're using.

- **GnuPG 1**: Use `--no-use-agent` to prevent GnuPG from asking the agent (which results in the pin entry dialog being opened)
- **GnuPG 2**: There is no way to prevent the agent being asked. But (at least starting with GnuPG 2.1), you can use [`gpg-preset-passphrase`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/gpg_002dpreset_002dpassphrase.html) to make sure  `gpg-agent` already knows your passphrase and will not ask for it.

  At least on systems running Debian (and probably derivatives), it's hidden in `/usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphras`.

Answer (score 0):

The right workaround for GnuPG 2 (until the bug is fixed) is to use `--pinentry-mode error` (then `--batch` is not needed, but could still be used just in case).

Note that `gpg-preset-passphrase` is either useless or potentially insecure, as for this workaround to be useful, the passphrase would need to be cached permanently. Moreover, there may be some encrypted files for which one does not know the passphrase, in which case `gpg-preset-passphrase` cannot be used.